# Enable DTrace on Solaris 10 using NIS group

Tags: solaris, nis, dtrace

Anyone know how to enable DTrace on Solaris 10 box, based on a NIS group.

I am hoping to save some time rather than enabling Dtrace one by one for each user in the group by putting it in the /etc/user_attr.

Cheers, Muhammad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is create a NIS map for user_attr, and then set that in all the nsswitch.conf files for each host (NB. it's not listed at all by default, even though prof_attr and auth_attr are.)

(It shouldn't take you much thought to realise why putting it in NIS is a *bad idea*, but I'm guessing that you're a die-hard NIS shop and so you are already aware of the security risks with doing anything involving NIS.

For any others reading this, if you put it in your LDAP tree and authenticate the name services with SSL certificates then it's rather safer.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. NIS = bad, yeah, knows that, only problem is that we have some old boxes like hpux 11.11, solaris 7 and 8 in our infra.